# Smooth symmetric divisors in abelian varieties without points of order $2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $X=V/\Lambda$ be a complex abelian variety of dimension $g$, endowed with a polarization $M$ of type $(d_1, \ldots, d_g)$. A divisor $D \in |M|$ is called *symmetric* if $(-1)_X^*D=D$, namely if it is invariant for the standard involution. Let $X_2$ be the subgroup of points of order $2$ of $X$.

> **Question 1.** Under which conditions on $(X, \, M)$ is it possible to find a smooth symmetric divisor $D \in |M|$ such that $D \cap X_2 = \emptyset$?

> **(Stronger) Question 2.** Under which conditions on $(X, \, M)$ can we find a linear subsystem $\mathcal{L}$ of $|M|$ such that both the following conditions hold?
>
> - $\mathcal{L}$ is made by invariant divisors;
> - $\mathcal{L}$ is base-point free.

Any insight or reference would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is true if $(g,d)$ equals $(1,2)$.  Presumably Riemann-Roch on the Kummer surface settles the case of $g=2$.

Comment: What is precisely the linear system in the second question? If $M$ is such that $(-1)^*M\cong M$ then there is a decomposition $H^0(A,M)=H^0(A,M)^+ \oplus H^0(A,M)^{-}$ into invariant and anti-invariant sections. Each of these linear system give symmetric divisors, I think.

Comment: @DanieleA: right, I corrected the question according to your remark.